# Two variable function on an unbounded set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following function

$$f(x,y) = 3x^2 +5y^2 +2y -4x -2xy + 1$$

I know that $f$ has a critical point in $x=9/14$ and $y=-1/14$. Also, I know that it will be a local minimum. How do I know (or check) that this value is a global minimum, that is, the lowest value of this function?

The domain is unbounded therefore I cannot apply Weierstrass Theorem. Do I count the limits? If yes, which of them? Is there a way to check that this function has a global minimum without even finding a local one?

Comment: How would you determine this for a single-variable function?

Comment: I would find a local minimum and compare it to border values - in this case to limits in infinity and negative infinity. Then I would choose the lowest value and that would be my global minimum.

Comment: Don’t confuse a function’s asymptotic values with values that it actually takes on. $\exp(-x^2)$ tends to zero, but it has no minimum value of any kind on $\mathbb R$. Infimum and minimum are not the same thing.

Comment: Then what happens if function asymptotically gets to the value $v$ which is lower than our local minimum? Will the global minimum be any value that is arbitrarily close to $v$ ?

Comment: There is no global minimum in that case. For any value you choose between the local minimum and that asymptotic value, you can always find an element of the domain for which the value of the function is even lower.

Comment: Okay, that is reasonable. Then what I need to do is to prove that there is nothing lower in value than my local minimum. I already know how to prove it algebraically. But when it comes to more analytical proof, how do I really prove that values of my function grow in any direction from minimum point?

Comment: That would mean computing the directional derivatives in every direction from my minimum towards infinity and showing that those derivatives are monotonic and they grow. Of course my idea seems stupid and impossible, so is there any other way?

Comment: Well, in my coursebook I found that if we want to test for global minimum in an unbounded domain, we have to calculate the limit while $x^2 +y^2$ go to infinity, but why is it so? I have no idea

Comment: Examining only directional derivatives might not be enough since those only examine straight lines through the point, and anyway, since you’re at a critical point, they all vanish. Why not just show that the function is convex?

Comment: Aye, that would prove my statement.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x,y) = 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 + 2 y - 4 x - 2 x y - 11 = (p-p_0)^{\top}M(p-p_0)+c
$$

with $p = (x,y), p_0 = (9/4,-1/14), c = 173/14$ and $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & -1\\
-1 & 5
\end{array}\right)$ with $M > 0$ so $f(x,y)$ has a global minimum.

Comment: I do not understand the T with upper index part. What is this?

Answer (score -1):

$f_x = 6x-4 - 2y = 0 = f_y=10y+2-2x \implies 3(10y+2)-4-2y=0\implies28y=-2\implies y = -\dfrac{1}{14}\implies x = \dfrac{9}{14}$ . Thus $\left(\dfrac{9}{14}, -\dfrac{1}{14}\right)$ is the only critical point that is a local minima as confirmed by you. Hence this is also the global minima since the domain is an open unbounded set.

Comment: In contrast to functions of one variable there are function of two variables

Comment: I do not understand the reasoning which led to the statement in last sentence. How do you know it's a global minimum? What if we had a functions that let's say had a limit equal 0 while x,y approached infinity? Then we would have the lowest value in infinity and I can't see where your reasoning takes this fact into account.

Comment: @mrrobot1337 “Infinity” is not a real number. Don’t confuse asymptotic values with actual values that the function takes on.